# Nodejs req.sessionID occasionally changes after redirect

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, sessionid

I am using nodejs, express and connect-memcaced to handle my sessions. I've made a login script which executes perfectly every time, sets the session data and marks the user as logged in and than redirects him back to the page he logged in from. What happens on occasion (not always) is that after he is redirected and the page loads the cookies sessionID changes and the user is off course not logged in anymore. I have failed finding the reason why this happens and why it doesn't happen every time.

Code snipet of the login function:

```
DB.getOne('User',{filters:{'primary':{email:req.body.email}}}, function(err,data){
  if(data[0] && data[0].active == 1){
    var encodedPass = self.encodePass(req.body.pass,req.body.email);
    if(encodedPass == data[0].pass){
      req.session.pr.user = data[0];
      req.session.pr.user.status = true; 
      res.writeHead(302, {
        'Location': goTo 
      });
      res.end();
    }
  }
});
```

Looking directly into memcached I can see that this executes perfectly and the data is always saved into memcached under the original sessionID. For some reason the redirect must be changing the sessionID

Comment: Is the session cookie being saved with a default path that differs from your redirect URL?

Comment: Could you post the order of the middleware you're using with Express?

Answer (score 0):

I often find that this happens to me when I do not notice that I have restarted the development server. Remember that the session cookies are stored in memory, so when the server is restarted, all the sessions will be forgotten and the user will be assigned a new session automatically.

Comment: OP is using `connect-memcached` to store sessions, which should survive a restart of the Node process.

Comment: True - I was a little too quick there. But the answer still applies if he is restarting memcached, or the sessions expire out of memcached because of space/time